# SMTP server not sending DSN

Tags: email, postfix, smtp, sendmail, dsn

Is the outgoing smtp server expected to notify sender of failure in upstream transfer giving this scenario?:

User A tries to send email message via his Outgoing SMTP (A-SMTP) server to recipient B.
Outgoing SMTP (A-SMTP) server accepts message and notifies the sender of succesfull trasmit.

Hovewer when A-SMTP contacts the incoming SMTP server of recipient (B-SMTP) the B-SMTP rejects the message because A-SMTP is trying to use weak TLS cipher.

**B-SMTP** sees '403 4.7. 0 TLS handshake failed' with **RST** packet

**A-SMTP** sees in his mail log: **status=deferred (Cannot start TLS: handshake failure)**

Answer (score 0):

It is a temporary error.

A-SMTP will retry and if it is not fixed eventually deliver "delay" and "undeliverable" NDRs to user A.